# User Input parsing for keywords C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, alias

I'm getting back into programming for the first time in over a decade and I'm a little rusty in C++.

I decided to make a zork type game that has a text based user prompt for all player actions but I wanted to parse the string input (i'm using getline(cin,MyString)) for keywords and interprete the desire of the user.  I'm looking to have some sort of alias so that if user types any of the following: yes, y, Yes, Yesir, Yessem, Yep, Uh-Huh, etc that it will interprete it as "yes" and not have a giant case statement.  I'm going to have this for a number of keywords and I want to easily add more.

I'm looking to have the game compare the keyword to a list of keywords in a text file and determine what the base keyword to use so I can determine an action from their input.

Are there any established libraries or practices that I could use for this functionality?

Currently looking at something like this:

```
Get user input
Check user input for keywords
Put each keyword into a class
assign class variable for the alias aka Keyword.type()="yes" or Keyword.type()="north"
Perform action based on keywords
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an action class for all possible cases.

```
class Action
{
public:
    virtual void doAction(YourGame*)=0;
};

class YesAction : public Action
{
public:
    void doAction(YourGame* game) {/* your yes logic */}
};
class NoAction : public Action
{
public:
    void doAction(YourGame* game) {/* your no logic */}
};
```

Then, in your `YourGame`, have a `std::map<std::string, Action*> actionMap`.

```
Action* yesAction = new YesAction();
actionMap["yes"] = yesAction;
actionMap["yep"] = yesAction;
actionMap["yeah"] = yesAction;
```

When you get user input, use `actionMap.find(userInput)` to get the possible action, and if it's not `actionMap.end()` (which means no such action), call doAction of the Action instance you get.

You'd also want to have functions such as `isValid` that checks whether the given action is valid for the current state in `YourGame`. doAction may call YourGame functions, or even change states.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Ternary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree)?

An implementation is [here.](https://www.abc.se/~re/code/tst/tst_docs/index.html)